# Validating JCL with conditional logic

Tags: mainframe, jcl, ispf

Normally, when I am done looking at a JCL, I will type the JEM command into my ISPF command line and that will do a quick scan and tell me any errors, such as files not allocated.

The only problem is, when we have IF statements in the JCL, the JEM will skip over these sections. So even though the JCL JEM-ed clean, I can still end up with JCL errors. Is there anyway that I can validate the JCL, other than actually checking that every single file is allocated?

Comment: JEM is an edit macro associated with ASG Software's JOB/SCAN product.  You may have access to a more configurable version of what JEM is doing via an ISPF dialog, if that part of the product was installed and made available to you.  Talk to your technical staff, this may be a bug in the product, potentially one fixed by maintenance yet to be applied.

Comment: @cschneid I don't know what I would do without you guys! The part that sucks about being a young person in the world of mainframe is that I have no idea how the big picture works. I know how to code, but when things like JEM don't work like I want them to, I have no idea where to even begin looking. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is check the condition code handling logic by using programs that can issue condition codes to replace the actual programs.

For a program that issues Cond code 0, simply replace the jcl for the step with a step that invokes the **`IEFBR14`** programs.

e.g. replace the step with

```
//STEP010 EXEC PGM=IEFBR14
```

(including any condition code checking from the original step)

For a program that issues a condition code (e.g. 8 )you can use **`IDCAMS`** with that has `SET MAXCC=8` e.g.

```
//STEP010 EXEC PGM=IDCAMS
//SYSIN    DD *
  MAXCC = 8
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
```

You could quite easily write a program Rexx, Cobol PL1 that could take a parameter as the code.

I personally had an assembler program called CCFIN (this could also issue User Abends) which was :-

```
         TITLE 'ISSUE COND CODE OR ABEND'                               00001000
         PRINT NOGEN                                                    00001100
         INIT  REGNUM=1                STANDARD INITIALISATION          00001200
*--------------------------------------------------------------------   00001301
*        GET PARAMETER INFORMATION                                      00001401
*--------------------------------------------------------------------   00001501
         L     2,0(1)                  AD OF PARAMETER                  00001601
         SR    3,3                                                      00001701
         LH    3,0(2)                  GET LENGTH OF PARAMETER          00001801
         CH    3,=H'0'                 CHECK IF ANY PARAMETER           00001901
         BH    CCFIN001                OK SO FAR                        00002001
TO_SHORT WTO   'CCFIN01 - NO PARAMETER GIVEN',ROUTCDE=(2),DESC=(1)      00002101
ERR_END  L     13,4(13)                                                 00002203
         RETURN (14,12),RC=1                                            00002301
CCFIN001 CH    3,=H'6'                 MAX LENGTH OF 6                  00002401
         BH    CCERET01                ERROR > 6                        00002502
*--------------------------------------------------------------------   00002601
*        CHECK TO SEE IF USER ABEND IS REQUIRED (UA????)                00002701
*--------------------------------------------------------------------   00002801
         MVC   UFLAG(1),=C'N'          DEFAULT NO                       00002901
         CH    3,=H'3'                 IS PARAMETER < 3                 00003001
         BL    CCFIN030                YES THEN CANT BE USER ABEND      00003101
         CLC   2(2,2),=C'UA'           CHECK FOR USER ABEND             00003201
         BE    CCFIN020                                                 00003301
         CH    3,=H'4'                 NOT USER ABEND SO MAX LEN IS 4   00003401
         BH    CCERET02                ERROR                            00003502
         B     CCFIN030                NOT USER ABEND BUT LEN OK        00003601
CCFIN020 MVC   UFLAG(1),=C'Y'          SET USER ABEND REQUIRED          00003701
         LA    5,1(0,0)                                                 00003801
         B     CCFIN031                                                 00003901
*--------------------------------------------------------------------   00004001
*        CONVERT PARAMETER TO COMPLETEION CODE                          00004101
*--------------------------------------------------------------------   00004201
CCFIN030 LA    5,1(0,0)                                                 00004301
CCFIN031 LA    4,NSTR                                                   00004401
         LA    2,1(2)                  SKIP PARAMETER LENGTH            00004501
         MVC   0(4,4),=C'0000'         ENSURE LEFT PAD WITH 0           00004601
         LA    4,3(4)                  END OF AREA                      00004701
         AR    2,3                     END OF PARAMETER LIST            00004801
         CLC   UFLAG(1),=C'Y'          USER ABEND                       00004901
         BNE   CCFIN032                                                 00005001
         SR    3,5                                                      00005101
         SR    3,5                                                      00005201
CCFIN032 MVC   0(1,4),0(2)                                              00005301
         SR    2,5                                                      00005401
         SR    4,5                                                      00005501
         BCT   3,CCFIN032                                               00005601
*--------------------------------------------------------------------   00005701
*        NUMERICS ONLY                                                  00005801
*--------------------------------------------------------------------   00005901
         LA    4,NSTR                                                   00006001
         LA    3,4                                                      00006101
CCFIN040 CLC   0(1,4),=X'F0'                                            00006201
         BL    CCERET03                                                 00006302
         CLC   0(1,4),=X'F9'                                            00006401
         BH    CCERET03                                                 00006502
         LA    4,1(4)                                                   00006601
         BCT   3,CCFIN040                                               00006701
*--------------------------------------------------------------------   00006801
*        CONVERT NUMBER TO BINARY INTO R15                              00006901
*--------------------------------------------------------------------   00007001
         PACK  PSTR,NSTR(4)                                             00007101
         CVB   15,PSTR                                                  00007201
         CLC   UFLAG(1),=C'Y'                                           00007301
         BE    FINUA                                                    00007401
FINCC    L     13,4(13)                                                 00007501
         RETURN (14,12),RC=(15)                                         00007601
FINUA    LR    2,15                                                     00007701
         CL    2,=F'4095'                                               00007801
         BNH   FU0001                                                   00007901
         WTO   'CCFIN02 - USER ABEND CODE GREATER THAN 4095',          X00008001
               ROUTCDE=(2),DESC=(1)                                     00008101
         SR    2,2                                                      00008201
FU0001   ABEND (2)                                                      00008301
CCERET01 WTO   'CCFIN03 - PARAMETER GREATER THAN 6 CHARACTERS',        X00008401
               ROUTCDE=(2),DESC=(1)                                     00008501
         B     ERR_END                                                  00008603
CCERET02 WTO   'CCFIN04 - PARAMETER GREATER THAN 4 CHARACTERS',        X00008701
               ROUTCDE=(2),DESC=(1)                                     00008801
         B     ERR_END                                                  00008903
CCERET03 WTO   'CCFIN05 - NON NUMERICS CHARACTERS IN PARAMETER',       X00009001
               ROUTCDE=(2),DESC=(1)                                     00009101
         B     ERR_END                                                  00009203
         FINISH                                                         00009300
UFLAG    DS    CL1                                                      00010001
NSTR     DS    1F                                                       00020001
PSTR     DS    D'0'                                                     00030001
         END                                                            00036900
```

The JCL for the above (to issue a condition code of 8) would then be:-

```
//STEP010 EXEC PGM=CCFIN,PARM="8"
//STEPLIB  DD DSN=MY.LOADLIB,DISP=SHR
```

#### Example

Assuming that the production(sic) JCL to be tested was :-

```
//CCOP010R JOB (@OPC,PROD,OPC),'MIKE TAYLOR',
// RESTART=STEP020,
// NOTIFY=CCOP010
//*--------------------------------------------------------------------
//STEP010 EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01,REGION=8M,TIME=10
//*
//* SELECT REQUIRED RECORDS FROM THE JOB/APPL XREF
//*
//SYSPROC  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=ISPF.EI.XGROUP.CLIST
//SYSEXEC  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=CCOP010.USER.EXEC
//SYSTPRT  DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSTSPRT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSTSIN  DD *
   OIR00001
//JXIN     DD DISP=SHR,DSN=CCOP010.JX.LIST
//JXOUT    DD DISP=SHR,DSN=CCOP010.JXMOD.LIST
//*--------------------------------------------------------------------
//STEP020 EXEC PGM=SORT,REGION=8M,COND=(0,NE)
//*
//* SORT BY APPLICATION OPNO AND JOBNAME REMOVING ANY DUPLICATES
//*
//SYSIN    DD *
  SORT FIELDS=(1,16,CH,A,19,3,CH,A,23,8,CH,A)
  SUM FIELDS=NONE
//SORTIN   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=CCOP010.JXMOD.LIST
//SORTOUT  DD DISP=(,PASS),DSN=&&STEP020A,UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(50,1))
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*
//*--------------------------------------------------------------------
//STEP030 EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01,REGION=8M,TIME=30,COND=(0,NE)
//*
//* SELECT REQUIRED RECORDS FROM THE JOB/APPL XREF
//*
//SYSPROC  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=ISPF.EI.XGROUP.CLIST
//SYSEXEC  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=CCOP010.USER.EXEC
//SYSTPRT  DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSTSPRT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSTSIN  DD *
   OIR00002
//JXIN     DD DISP=(SHR,DELETE),DSN=&&STEP020A
//OIIN     DD DISP=SHR,DSN=CCOP010.OI.LIST
//IEBOUT   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=CCOP010.OIPDS.DATA
//REPORT   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=CCOP010.OIPDS.REPORT
//*--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And we wanted to test to see if a condition code of 8 issued by STEP010 was handled correctly then :-

The above could be changed to :-

```
//CCOP010R JOB (@OPC,PROD,OPC),'MIKE TAYLOR',
// RESTART=STEP020,
// NOTIFY=CCOP010
//*--------------------------------------------------------------------
//STEP010 EXEC PGM=IDCAMS
//*
//* SELECT REQUIRED RECORDS FROM THE JOB/APPL XREF
//*
//SYSIN    DD *
  MAXCC = 8
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//*--------------------------------------------------------------------
//STEP020 EXEC PGM=IEFBR14,COND=(0,NE)
//*
//* SORT BY APPLICATION OPNO AND JOBNAME REMOVING ANY DUPLICATES
//*
//*--------------------------------------------------------------------
//STEP030 EXEC PGM=IEFBR14,COND=(0,NE)
//*
//* SELECT REQUIRED RECORDS FROM THE JOB/APPL XREF
//*
//*--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### Note! serious consideration should be given to the impact that not changing Jobname and accounting info could have. i.e. It would be advisable to change these to suit the in-house use.

*e.g. Running a job with the same name as a job that is run and tracked via a scheduler could interfere with the production schedule.*

Answer (score 2):

Use `TYPRUN=SCAN` in your jobcard and submit the job. This will do the syntax checking but your job will Not be run.

Keep in mind that it'll Not do checks such as "file doesn't exist".

.